# Excel Export Blank Sheet Problem

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I've had some code that has worked for years to export an html table to Excel.  It goes like this-

```
private void ExcelExport ( string core_number )
    {
      // set response up for excel export
      Response.Clear ();
      Response.Buffer = true;
      Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
      Response.AddHeader ( "content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TEST.xls" );

 .. loops through generates an simple html table ...


   Response.Write ( "</table>" );
   Response.Flush ();
   Response.End();
}
```

I noticed Firefox now shows the file as an XML document instead of a Excel document, and when I open the generated document it will parse fail.  Also some users report having export problems in some older versions of IE, even though I'm not having any problems in IE on my end (shows as an Excel document and opens properly).

Anyone seen this one before?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe worth checking the install options for Excel where people are having problems. There is a chance they don't have some of the interop or shared components installed, which might be why the content-type is not handled correctly in MSIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't find an answer, but worked around it for now.

Comment: I wish you would've posted the work around.

I am getting an issue on Excel export (using the standard "convert HTML table to Excel" all over the web) when the user clicks the "Open" button in Internet Explorer. Doing that launches Excel and just shows a blank screen (no document open). Clicking "Save" or "Save As" saves the file to disk and then the user can open. But I am required to get that stupid "Open" button working, and I'm really at a loss...